# Google code jam APAC test seven segment display

Tags: c++

I am trying to solve **Google Code Jam APAC test Seven segment display** problem. 
***https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/3214486/dashboard***
I have implemented the solution using minimum hamming distance between string consisting binary's of 98765432109876 and the given string of N.
I am unable to understand cases when there result will be unambigious to print **ERROR!**.
Here is my solution-

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstring>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;
     char str[]="111101111111111110000101111110110110110011111100111011010110000111111011110111111111111000010111111011011";
     int l=strlen(str);

    for(int k=1;k<=t;k++)
    {
     int n;
      cin>>n;
       l=10*7+(n-1)*7;
      char num[50];
      for(int i=0;i<7*n;i++)
      {
            char ch;
            cin>>ch;
            if(ch!=' ')
             num[i]=ch;

      }
      int ok[7]={0};
      for(int i=0;i<7*n;i++)
      {
          ok[i%7]=ok[i%7]|(num[i]-'0');
      }

      int mn_dst=10000,dt=0,f=0,pos=0;
      int xor_res[9]={0},txor_res[9]={0},z=0;

      for(int i=0;i<=(l-(7*n));i=i+7)
      {
          dt=0;
          z=0;
          memset(txor_res,0,sizeof(int)*9);

        for(int j=0;j<7*n;j++){
            if((str[j+i]=='1'&&num[j]=='0'&&ok[j%7]==1)||(str[j+i]=='0'&&num[j]=='1'))
            {z=1;
             break;
            }
          if(str[j+i]!=num[j])
            {dt++;
             txor_res[j%7]=1;
            }

                              }
            if(z==1)
              continue;

             if(dt==mn_dst)
                {f=1;
                  break;
                }
             if(mn_dst!=10000)
             {f=1;
              break;
             }
             if(dt<mn_dst)
             {
                 mn_dst=dt;
                 dt=0;
                 pos=i;
                 for(int h=0;h<=7;h++)
                 {
                   xor_res[h]=txor_res[h];
                   txor_res[h]=0;
                 }

             }

      }

        if(f==1||mn_dst==10000)
         cout<<"Case #"<<k<<": "<<"ERROR!\n";
        else
         {
             cout<<"Case #"<<k<<": ";

             pos=pos+7*n;
             for(int i=pos;i<(pos+7);i++)
                {

                      cout<<str[i];
                }
         cout<<"\n";
         }

    }
}
```

**I don't want to bother anyone by understanding my code.Instead I want a new approach.**

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem in understanding the question as you. I downloaded A-small-practice.in. I ran someone's correct solution and we produce different outputs in the following cases -

## Case 1

Input

```
1 0001011
```

My Output -

```
Case #18: 0100011
```

Correct Output -

```
Case #18: ERROR!
```

## Case 2

Input

```
1 0011111
```

My Output -

```
Case #27: 0011011
```

Correct Output -

```
Case #27: ERROR!
```

## Case 3

Input

```
1 1001111
```

My Output -

```
Case #66: 1001011
```

Correct Output -

```
Case #66: ERROR!
```

## Case 4

Input

```
1 1111110
```

My Output -

```
Case #73: 1111011
```

Correct Output -

```
Case #73: ERROR!
```

## Case 5

Input

```
1 1011101
```

My Output -

```
Case #74: 1011001
```

Correct Output -

```
Case #74: ERROR!
```

## Case 6

Input

```
2 1001001 1001101
```

My Output -

```
Case #77: 0000000
```

Correct Output -

```
Case #77: ERROR!
```

## Case 7

Input

```
1 0111011
```

My Output -

```
Case #81: 0111111
```

Correct Output -

```
Case #81: ERROR!
```

## Case 8

Input

```
1 1011011
```

My Output -

```
Case #94: 0110011
```

Correct Output -

```
Case #94: ERROR!
```

All of the cases where my output doesn't match, it is because the correct output is "ERROR!", while I am able to find an unambiguous next state. Can you or someone else point out why my solution is not the only unambiguous state? :) Any other pointers would be appreciated too.

Let's figure out the exact meaning of this problem together one case at a time :D

Comment: Never mind, I understood why my outputs were wrong already :-) I will give you a link to my solution which works on the practice data at least soon.

Comment: You can view the solutions of everyone here - https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/3214486/scoreboard#vf=1 You can find many versions of the correct solution because lots of folks have solved this problem during the competition :)

Comment: Please why this test case : `2 0010011 1011001` have to give `ERROR` us output , instead of : `1001101`  , as I think that the first number can be 4 , the second 3 so the next state will be 2 !!

Comment: @FouadWahabi Did  you find an answer?

Comment: @FouadWahabi I recently solved the question. There are other sequences possible with your input; <9,8> and <6,5>